# Differences Between 2 WordPress Installations using Same Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

I have two sites, both using the same code and same version of WordPress (3.6.1). The site theme is based heavily on the Reverie Foundation theme using Foundation 4.0.

(BETA Site) http://tallistowp.betaforming.com/features/

(LIVE Site) http://www.tallisto.com/features/

The main navigation is hard coded:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/features/"<?php if ($url_folder == "features") { echo ' class="current"';} ?> >Features</a></li>
<li><a href="/news/"<?php if ($url_folder == "news") { echo ' class="current"';} ?> >News</a></li>
<li><a href="/blog/"<?php if ($url_folder == "blog") { echo ' class="current"';} ?> >Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="/about/"<?php if ($url_folder == "about") { echo ' class="current"';} ?> >About</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact/"<?php if ($url_folder == "contact") { echo ' class="current"';} ?> >Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/join/"<?php if ($url_folder == "join") { echo ' class="current-signup"';} ?> class="subscribe-button">Signup</a></li>
<li><a href="https://app.tallisto.com/login.php" class="login-button">Login</a>
</ul>
```

Using this code to determine the "current" page to apply active page styling.

```
<?php
// get folder name for active navigation styling
$url_folder = substr(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1), "/"));
?>
```

On the BETA site, it does work as long as the trailing slash is on the link. If I remove it, I loose the $url_folder variable and the "current" class isn't set.

On the LIVE site, the trailing slash is getting automatically removed for some reason, but it doesn't work either way.

Another oddity that escapes me is the BETA site is rendering bigger all around than the LIVE site.  It's like the LIVE site is getting scaled down about 5-10%.

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely that if the trailing slash is being removed on live but not beta, then the .htaccess files aren't the same on each site.  For me, the slash isn't being removed on either, and the navigation is highlighting fine.

If the site is scaling down on one server, I suspect that you've inadvertently zoomed out at some point, and your browser is remembering the change.  Try visiting each, and pressing CTRL and '=' at the same time to reset these - works for most browsers.

Comment: Yes, the site was scaling for some reason.  Thanks for the fix.  The issue with the navigation is a bit weird.  The .htaccess files are the same. It renders correctly on Win7 (IE, FF and Chrome), Mac (Chrome and Safari) but it doesn't highlight the active link in Mac FF or on the iPhone and iPad.  The trailing slash is getting dropped on those three.